# Package-wise compilation with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am new to Maven, we are converting ant based project into Maven project. Every thing is working fine. Additionally we need to compile source code package wise.

To be more clear, we have three packages in src/main/java folder, namely dao, svc and controller. I want to compile dao first and then compile svc by giving dao reference to it, similarly compile controller by giving reference of svc only but not dao.

Finally the goal is to make sure that the controllers are not using any of the dao classes, they can use svc classes only. If this condition fails, Maven build has to be failed.

Please suggest.

Comment: Split dao/svc/controller into multiple maven projects and set the dependencies accordingly.

Comment: Easiest way to achieve this is to split the project in three (and not have the controller import the dao).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [multi-module maven project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). Create a parent project, whose task is simply to aggregate your three modules and to provide one thing to build. Create one module for each of your packages, then define dependencies between those modules in the individual POM files.

The Maven build system is clever enough to know in which order to build the modules, based on the dependencies you declare between them. In cases where you don't define a dependency (e.g. between controller and dao), the controller module cannot access classes in the dao module.

The final source layout will be something like:

```
your-project
your-project/pom.xml   <--- parent POM

your-project/dao
your-project/dao/pom.xml
your-project/dao/src/main/...

your-project/svc
your-project/svc/pom.xml
your-project/svc/src/main/...

your-project/controller
your-project/controller/pom.xml
your-project/controller/src/main/...
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it might work. But may not be possible to divide existing project(already in production) into modules. If possible, could you please elaborate it more. How to provide reference of dao in svc?

Comment: @sree To provide a reference, you include a `<dependency>` entry in your SVC pom that points to your DAO artifact. It sounds like you need to do a bit of background reading on Maven - it's not super complicated, but you'll not get far without a grounding in the basics.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I did this. Finally i have a war file with svc & dao jars separately. And the application is working as expected. But can we have all my sub modules compiled source in classes folder instead of having them in jars?

Comment: One more issue. I have added dao dependency in svc pom. And svc dependency in controller pom. For testing i have used dao class in one controller, when i tried mvn install all controllers compiled successfully. What should we do to restrict this?

Comment: @sree It's probably best to ask these two questions as new questions. It's generally a bad idea to start fresh discussions in the comments of existing answers.

Comment: I have found a solution for this by excluding dao dependency from svc dependency in controller pom. Will do create new questions for further questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To be more clear, we have three packages in src/main/java folder, namely dao, svc and controller. I want to compile dao first and then compile svc by giving dao reference to it, similarly compile controller by giving reference of svc only but not dao.

Judging by your requirements, I think more or less you need to setup a maven based Multi Module project. Take a look at these links

1. [Link 1](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)
2. [Link 2](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: Thanks. It may not possible for me to divide the project now.